# Can't writeFile to the dist folder using Promise, catch and gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm mapping an index.html file to **scrape** the  tag content and save as a file called fonts.css

This is my style:

```
<style>@font-face{font-family:Averti;src:url(https://services.serving-sys.com/HostingServices/custdev/site-140253/Averti/Averti-Bold.woff) format('truetype');font-weight:700;font-style:normal}@font-face{font-family:Averti-Light;src:url(https://services.serving-sys.com/HostingServices/custdev/site-140253/Averti_Webfonts/Averti-Light.woff) format('truetype');font-weight:400;font-style:normal}</style>
```

There is no major errors with the function, but the console.log is showing me that
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './dist/css/fonts.css']
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: './dist/css/fonts.css' }

I'm not sure if that is right as the file is not even created yet.

See my function below and let me know what I am missing.

Thank you in advance.

```
async function createStyle(){

var jsonObject = [] 

setTimeout(function(){  

fs.readFile('./dist/index.html', 'utf8',  function(err, html){
    if (!err){
        const $ = cheerio.load(html)
        var cssScript = $('head > style').map(( i, x ) => x.children[0])
                                         .filter(( i, x ) => x && x.data.match(/@font-face/)).get(0);
        jsonObject.push(cssScript)
        exportStyle(jsonObject)
    }
})}, 2000); 

async function exportStyle(_json) {

const stylePromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    fs.writeFile('./dist/css/fonts.css', _json, err => {
        if (err) {
            reject();
        } else {                                
            resolve();
            console.log('Created: fonts.css');                                                     
        }            
        console.log(err);                             
        });
});
       (async function() {
           try {
                await stylePromise;
         } catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
         }
})();}}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if your code was properly broken into separate lines where intended and indented to match.

Comment: Does `./dist/css` exist?

Comment: ./dist/css do not exist as it's a gulp task and suppose to create it when running gulp.

Comment: the indentation is not properly, because when placing the code in the editor, it comes out of the code area

Comment: the index.html exists in the dist folder

Comment: If `./dist/css` does not exist when you try to call `fs.writeFile('./dist/css/fonts.css', ...)`, then you will get an error.  It seems like that might be what is happening.  `fs.writeFile()` will create the file, but not the directory.

Comment: I'm not interested in "why" the formatting of your code is messed up.  I'm asking you to fix it so people are more likely to help you.  Your code as it shows in your question is NOT readable.  When I actually put it in a code formatter and formatted it appropriately, it shows an entirely different flow than what it looks like now.  Please fix it, even if you have to do it manually.  Yes, the code formatting capabilities here in stackoverflow are bad, but they are what they are and if you want more people to help you, you have to post readable code.

Comment: @jfriend00 can you read the code now?

Comment: Still not indented properly which helps you see and follow the code flow.  This code is oddly structured and one can only understand the odd structure when you see the proper indentation.

Comment: Ok @jfriend00, gotcha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the css and js folder inside the ./dist folder and the code worked like a charm. Other than that, the error message appears in the console.